# Referencing an open excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

fairly new to VBA in excel and having an issue with trying to reference an already-opened workbook. The code below works well until I get to the line where I try to activate the ProductionBook. I get the "subscript out of range" error here which leads me to believe that the workbook is not being activated. Any ideas on how I can overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub UpdateSales()

'---Code written in the open workbook defined as ProductionBook

Dim ProductionBook As Workbook 'Master file
Dim sbSolvents As Workbook 'S&P BW-query workbook
Dim path1 As String

'---------Define path directory for S&P workbook-------------
path1 = "C:\Users\scullycs\Desktop\P&O\BW Files\Shipped & Pending\January\ISOP.xlsm"

Set sbSolvents = Workbooks.Open(path1)

With sbSolvents
    Range("j19:j36").Select
    Selection.Copy
End With

Set ProductionBook = Workbooks("Master Production File.xlsm")

With ProductionBook
    Worksheets("S&OP Progress").Range("F11").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) 'this is where I get the subscript error
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your issue is you are not defining which `Worksheet` in `sbSolvents` workbook you want to copy from

Comment: have you tried the solution and my code below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below (in the 3rd line from the bottom, you need to modify "Sheet1" to your sheet in `sbSolvents` that you want to copy from).

```
Sub UpdateSales()

'---Code written in the open workbook defined as ProductionBook

Dim ProductionBook As Workbook 'Master file
Dim sbSolvents As Workbook 'S&P BW-query workbook
Dim path1 As String

'---------Define path directory for S&P workbook-------------
path1 = "C:\Users\scullycs\Desktop\P&O\BW Files\Shipped & Pending\January\ISOP.xlsm"

Set sbSolvents = Workbooks.Open(path1)
Set ProductionBook = Workbooks("Master Production File.xlsm")

' modify "Sheet1" in the line below to your sheet name
sbSolvents.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J19:J36").Copy
ProductionBook.Worksheets("S&OP Progress").Range("F11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```